# React navigation override drawer safeareaview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How could i override/customized the default `SafeAreaView` provided with `react-navigation`/`react-navigation-drawer`.

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/handling-iphonex.html

I try to override by enclosing `<SafeAreaView></SafeAreaView>` as follow in the component/view but it ends up having duplicate `SafeAreaView` UI instead. Meaning that it append another `SafeAreaView` instead of overriding the default built in `SafeAreaView` of `react-navigation`.

```
<SafeAreaView
  style={{flex: 1}}
  forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }}>
  ...
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a custom `contentComponent` for your drawer:

```
const DrawerNavigatorConfig = {
  contentComponent: props => <Menu {...props} />
};
createDrawerNavigator(RouteConfigs, DrawerNavigatorConfig);
```

You would need to implement that `Menu` component... which could be like:

```
const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView
        forceInset={{ top: 'always', bottom: 'never' }}
         style={{flex: 1}}
    >
        ...
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```